# 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found in swift5 on ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, appdelegate

I have a problem using FireBase. I had no problem with the build, but there was an error with the Firebase in iOS10.3 and I tried the suggested solution.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

And then I erased the cache and rebuilt it. However, the error has been changed.

> 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found Could not build // firebase.h
>
> Objective-C module 'Firebase' // Appdelegate.swift

**my podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'testtest' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
     use_frameworks!

    # Pods for DeleteMe
    pod 'SwiftSVG', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'Toaster'
    pod 'BigInt', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'CryptoSwift'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'web3.swift.pod', '~> 2.2.0'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core' 
end
```

I erased Pod and tried to rebuild it, but the error was the same.

1. $ pod deintegrate
2. $ pod clean
3. $ pod install

How can you solve this problem?

- Xcode : Version 11.0
- realDevice : iphone5 10.3

[image: device info]

### I just built my other test iPhone 6 version 12.4, but there was no error. There seems to be a problem in version 10.3.

Comment: did you try running `pod install --verbose` to see the cause?

Comment: I wasn't tried `pod install --verbose` Does this solve my problem?

Comment: you should certainly see what went wrong with that command